# AWS elastic search cluster becoming unresponsive

Tags: aws-elasticsearch

we have several AWS elastic search domains which sometimes become unresponsive for no apparent reason. The ES endpoint as well as Kibana return bad gateway errors after a few minutes of trying to load the resources.

The node status message is the following (not that it's any help):
/_cluster/health: {"code":"ProxyRequestServiceException","message":"Unable to execute HTTP request: Read timed out (Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)"}

Error logs are activated for the cluster but do not show anything relevant for the time at which the cluster became inactive.

I would like to at least be able to restart the cluster but the status remains "processing" seemingly forever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you are using the AWS ElasticSearch Service (as in not building it on your own EC2 instances), many... well... MOST... of the admin API's and capabilities are restricted so you cannot dig as much into it as you could if you built it from the ground up.

I have found that AWS Support does a pretty good job in getting to the bottom of things when needed, so I would suggest you open a support ticket.

I wish this wasn't the case, but using their service is nice and easy (as in you don't have to build and maintain the infra yourself), but you lose a LOT of capabilities from an Admin or Troubleshooting perspective. :(

Comment: thanks you are confirming my impressions. I would upvote you had I the necessary points to do so.